# override/overload the + operator to operate on common lisp vectors

Tags: operator-overloading, common-lisp, overriding

I wish to overload the + operator to work on common lisp vectors -- just as it would for vectors in linear algebra. Is it possible to overload with the `+` operator?

Here is my intended definition:

```
 (defmethod + ((v1 vector) (v2 vector))
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 8):

If I were to do this, I would start by doing it in a separate package. I would then write a general function that uses binary operators:

```
(defun + (&rest addends)
  (reduce #'binary+ (cdr addends) :initial-value (car addends)))

(defgeneric binary+ (addend1 addend2))
```

Then you can define methods on the generic function `binary+` that would allow you to add two vectors, a vector and a scalar, ...

Something that would be a suitable wrapper-generating macro:

```
(defmacro define-operator (op &key (binary-signifier :binary) (package *package*)
  "Defines a generic operator OP, being essentially a reduce operation using
   a generic function whose name is a concatenation of BINARY-SIGNIFIER and OP."
  (let ((op op)
        (binary (intern (concatenate 'string
                                          (string  binary-signifier)
                                          (string op))
                        package)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,op (&rest args)
          (reduce (function ,binary) (cdr args) :initial-value (car args)))
       (defgeneric ,binary (arg1 arg2)))))
```

Then you can define methods, as per Joshua Taylor's answer:

```
(defmethod binary+ ((x number) (y number))
  (cl:+ x y))

(defmethod binary+ ((x vector) (y vector))
  (map 'vector 'cl:+ x y))

(defmethod binary+ ((x list) (y list))
  (map 'list 'cl:+ x y))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-generate the wrapping defun?" I am not an experienced Lisp programmer.

Comment: At the end of the day I would like to be able to write both (+ 1 1) which equals 2 and (+ #(1 2) #(0 -1)) which equals #(1 1)

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus, can you tell me why do you want to do it? In any language one should try to do work in most idiomatic way. While operator overloading is OK in other languages, and generic functions is OK in some cases in Common lisp, making `+` generic is useless in Common Lisp. You can easily solve your problem with `map`, as I showed, or if you really need one function to process numbers and vectors, then create new one.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Vatine's answer will allow you to "write both (+ 1 1) which equals 2 and (+ #(1 2) #(0 -1)) which equals #(1 1)".

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25205788/1281433) that extends this approach and shows how it works in a bit more detail.

Comment: @Vatine I've marked that answer community wiki because it's really just a few more lines of code added to what you already had.  If you want to incorporate it into your answer, feel free!

Answer (score 5):

This is an extension of [Vatine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25159681/1281433), but with some more detail to make the implementaiton clearer:

```
(defpackage #:generic-arithmetic 
  (:use "COMMON-LISP")
  (:shadow "+"))

(in-package #:generic-arithmetic)

(defun + (&rest addends)
  (reduce 'binary+ (cdr addends) :initial-value (car addends)))

(defgeneric binary+ (addend1 addend2))

(defmethod binary+ ((x number) (y number))
  (cl:+ x y))

(defmethod binary+ ((x vector) (y vector))
  (map 'vector 'cl:+ x y))

(defmethod binary+ ((x list) (y list))
  (map 'list 'cl:+ x y))
```

```
(+ 1 1)
;=> 2

(+ #(1 2) #(0 -1))
;=> #(1 1)

(+ '(1 3) '(3 1))
;=> (4 4)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my answer and also added a wrapper-generating macro.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to redefine `+` if you shadow it first:

```
? (shadow '+)

? (defgeneric + (a &rest b))

? (defmethod + ((a number) &rest b) (apply 'cl:+ a b))
? (+ 1 2)
3
? (+ 2 3 4)
9

? (defmethod + ((a string) &rest b) (apply #'cl:concatenate 'string a b))
? (+ "Hello" "World")
"HelloWorld"
? (+ "Hello" " cruel " "World")
"Hello cruel World"

? (defmethod + ((a vector) &rest b) (apply #'map 'vector 'cl:+ a b))
? (let ((v0 #(1 2 3)) (v1 #(4 5 6))) (+ v0 v1))
#(5 7 9)
```

Comment: you don't need to cons for `apply`: `(apply '+ 1 2 '(3 4))`

Comment: While this is good for a hack, it is not so good for production. Most obvious consequence from your approach is that function `+` now works slower (and I guess `+` is very common used function).

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not a good idea to define generic function `+`, because, well, this symbol is locked. CLOS is different from object systems in other languages, such as C++, so term `overload' is probably not quite correct.

Actually, you do not need a special function to sum vectors, use [`map`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm):

```
CL-USER> (let ((v0 #(1 2 3))
               (v1 #(4 5 6)))
           (map 'vector #'+ v0 v1))
#(5 7 9)
```